# How to respect execution order in NodeJS application with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

please help me understand how can I solve this.

**this is my routes file (auth-routes.js)**

```
const userControllers = require('../controllers/user')
module.exports = function(app){
  app.post('/auth/recuperarpassword', function(req, res){
    var info = userControllers.recuperarPassword(req, res)
    console.log('---------------->there is in routes file-->' + info);
    res.status(500).send(info)
  })
}
```

**and this is my controller file (user.js)**

```
    'use strict'
const User = require('../models/user')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
var momenttz = require('moment-timezone');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
function recuperarPassword(req,res){
  var username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim();
  console.log('----username:---->' + username + '<---------------');
  var info;
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err,user){
      console.log('Dentro del findOne');
      if (err) {
        console.log('--->Error - Error al buscar username en BD')
        return err
      }
      console.log('------>user:-->'+ user);
    })
  console.log('Salio del FinOne');
  info = {descerror: 'Elcomercio '}
  return info
}
module.exports = {
  recuperarPassword
}
```

**and in the console results are printed like this:**

```
----username:---->cesar4@mail.com<---------------
Salio del FinOne
---------------->Ya esta en routes-->[object Object]
POST /auth/recuperarpassword 500 42.647 ms - 27
Dentro del findOne
------>user:-->{ _id: 58fe681cb615c91f9d71adfb,
  username: 'cesar4@mail.com',
  password: 'hash',
  __v: 0 }
```

**instead of printing in the correct order, something similar like this:**

```
----username:---->cesar4@mail.com<---------------
Dentro del findOne
------>user:-->{ _id: 58fe681cb615c91f9d71adfb,
  username: 'cesar4@mail.com',
  password: 'hash',
  __v: 0 }
Salio del FinOne
---------------->Ya esta en routes-->[object Object]
POST /auth/recuperarpassword 500 42.647 ms - 27
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need callback mechanism. NodeJS is event based nonBlockingIO. So your control will not stop till the DB call is executed hence your `info` variable is returned before you get result from DB

**Let me know if you need more help on this.**

Your controller function should look like this

```
'use strict'
const User = require('../models/user')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
var momenttz = require('moment-timezone');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
function recuperarPassword(req,res, callback){
  var username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim();
  console.log('----username:---->' + username + '<---------------');
  var info;
  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err,user){
    console.log('Dentro del findOne');
    if (err) {
      console.log('--->Error - Error al buscar username en BD');
      callback(false);
      return err
    }
    console.log('------>user:-->'+ user);
    callback(user)
  });
}
module.exports = {
  recuperarPassword
};
```

Your route file should look like this

```
const userControllers = require('../controllers/user')
module.exports = function(app){
  app.post('/auth/recuperarpassword', function(req, res){
    userControllers.recuperarPassword(req, res, function(data){
      if(data === false){
        //there was error in your controller DB call
      }else{
        console.log('---------------->there is in routes file-->' + data);
        res.status(500).send(data)
      }
    });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your findOne function take time to fetch the data from database so it does not stop the flow of the execution of logic because :-

- Node Js is **Single thread** is doesnt stop .All you can achive in callback functions.
- Its is **non-blocking I/O model**

So , you can do it like this:-

```
    exports.recuperarPassword = function(req, res) {
        var username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim();
        console.log('----username:---->' + username + '<---------------');

        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            console.log('Dentro del findOne');
            if (err) {
                console.log('--->Error - Error al buscar username en BD')
                return err;
            }
            console.log('------>user:-->' + user);
            console.log('Salio del FinOne');
            user.info= { descerror: 'Elcomercio ' }; //if you want to use info object

            return user; 
        });


};
```

*All the things you want to be done just do it when result comes from database*

Comment: This wont work. you are returning `info` from a callback function so the return value of that callback function will be `info` but still it wont be available in the route file. You will need callback mechanism to solve this. Look at my answer. Hope that helps @hardy